# Delphi Position of Pos

Tags: delphi

So i have this following code that works:

```
function TForm2.SearchForm(Count: Integer): String;
var
  i,a,a1: integer;
  s,s0,s1,s2: string;
begin
  s := Memo1.Text;
  for i := 0 to Count-1 do
  begin
    a:=Pos('"last_ten_starts":"',s);
    s0:=Copy(s, 1, a);
    Delete(s, 1, a+18);
    a:=Pos('"', s);
    s1:=Copy(s, 1, a-1);//copy last 10 runs
    s2:=Copy(s1, Length(s1)-3, Length(s1));//get last 4 runs
    Memo1.Lines.Append('Form (x10): '+s1+ ' Form (x4): '+s2);
    if (s2 = '1111') or (s2 = '111x') or (s2 = '11x1') or (s2 = '1x11') or (s2 = 'x111') then
    begin
      Log(s0);
      ShowMessage('Pos: '+IntToStr(a));
    end;
  end;
end;

function TForm2.GetRaceNumber(Count: Integer): string;
var
  s, s1: string;
  i, a, a1: integer;
begin
  s := Memo1.Text;
  for i := 0 to Count-1 do
  begin
    a:=Pos('"RaceForm":{"@number":"',s);
    Copy(s, 1, a);
    Delete(s, 1, a+22);
    a1:=Pos('"', s);
    s1:=Copy(s, 1, a1-1);//copy race number
  end;
end;
```

All is good the code works, bit messy but tidy up can happen later. I am a bit confused about how to go about doing something.

It has me that confused that i am even struggling explaining what i need to try and do here.

So "RaceForm":{"@number":" has 8 occurrences and between those occurrences are about 90 "last_ten_starts":". What i need to do is check all 8 positions of RaceForm to determine if last_ten_starts is Race 1 to 8.

Does this make sense?

Edit: So here is my text example (btw i am reading a html to memo and searching for text)

```
RaceNumber: 1 Position: 23622
RaceNumber: 2 Position: 37026
RaceNumber: 3 Position: 74937
RaceNumber: 4 Position: 81592
RaceNumber: 5 Position: 82517
RaceNumber: 6 Position: 90886
RaceNumber: 7 Position: 95888
RaceNumber: 8 Position: 99938
```

So between Position 1 and 2, i want to read all the "last_ten_starts" and place them as Race 1. The positions between 2 and 3 "last_ten_starts" will be race 2.

At the moment the last ten starts look like this:

```
Form (x10): 6x49559545 Form (x4): 9545
Form (x10): 80x1071684 Form (x4): 1684
Form (x10): 9185215877 Form (x4): 5877
Form (x10): 5530017849 Form (x4): 7849
Form (x10): 4x83373x56 Form (x4): 3x56
Form (x10): 5970636148 Form (x4): 6148
Form (x10): 8x25785511 Form (x4): 5511
Form (x10): 668670x763 Form (x4): x763
Form (x10): x43530x956 Form (x4): x956
Form (x10): 83x2x11113 Form (x4): 1113
Form (x10): 15x3214533 Form (x4): 4533
Form (x10): 2149x8x830 Form (x4): x830
Form (x10): 6127x46325 Form (x4): 6325
```

But want the code to read them between the positonal blocks and place them like:

```
Race 1: Form (x10): 6x49559545 Form (x4): 9545
Race 1: Form (x10): 80x1071684 Form (x4): 1684
Race 1: Form (x10): 9185215877 Form (x4): 5877
Race 2: Form (x10): 5530017849 Form (x4): 7849
Race 2: Form (x10): 4x83373x56 Form (x4): 3x56
Race 3: Form (x10): 5970636148 Form (x4): 6148
Race 4: Form (x10): 8x25785511 Form (x4): 5511
Race 4: Form (x10): 668670x763 Form (x4): x763
Race 5: Form (x10): x43530x956 Form (x4): x956
Race 6: Form (x10): 83x2x11113 Form (x4): 1113
Race 7: Form (x10): 15x3214533 Form (x4): 4533
Race 8: Form (x10): 2149x8x830 Form (x4): x830
Race 8: Form (x10): 6127x46325 Form (x4): 6325
```

Comment: Yes, your explanation is not good. State the problem more clear, please, and show text example.

Comment: Yes sorry it is a bit hard to explain, wish i could explain it a little better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scan text simultaneously for both patterns. I'd recommend to use `PosEx` to continue search from the last position without deleting string pieces. Pseudocode:

```
RaceNum := 0;
LastPos := 1;
RacePos := PosEx('"RaceForm":{"@number":"', s, LastPos);
TenPos := PosEx('"last_ten_starts":"', s, LastPos);

while (RacePos > 0)  or (TenPos > 0) do begin

   if (RacePos > 0) then
      if (TenPos = 0) or (RacePos < TenPos) then begin
          Extract RaceNumber from race record
          //Update LastPos to the end of race record:
          LastPos := LastPos + Length('"RaceForm":{"@number":"');   
       end;

   if (TenPos > 0) then
      if (RacePos = 0) or (RacePos > TenPos) then begin
          Extract last_ten record
          Assign it to the current RaceNumber
          //Update LastPos to the end of last_ten record
          LastPos := LastPos + Length('"last_ten_starts":"');   
       end;

   RacePos := PosEx('"RaceForm":{"@number":"', s, LastPos);
   TenPos := PosEx('"last_ten_starts":"', s, LastPos);
end;
```

Comment: yes thank you, that was my problem! getting the lastpos

Comment: i also didn't know you could do it without deleting string pieces, because me doing so messes around with the positions of characters. Thanks this is very helpful!

Comment: To get new `lastpos` value, increment it by the length of pattern found

Comment: so like `NextPos := PosEx('"', s, RacePos + Length(Race));` Race being the string.

Comment: In that case logic might become too complex. See my update in if-conditions and Lastpos addition

Comment: that works perfectly, the other way crashed on the last race but this has fixed :)

Comment: Hasn't regular Pos() an optional "start" parameter since years?

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez  Yes (at least in Berlin): http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Pos

Comment: +MBo This was my point... Not a real question (I knew it was the case - just wanted to be a bit sarcastic). No need to use PosEx on modern Delphi: just use plain Pos() extended syntax.